# Basic HQL statement always fails

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hql

I've recently started trying to use Hibernate, but am doing so in Netbeans.  This has left me having to use [this example project](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/hibernate-webapp.html#06) to try and get me up and running.

Unfortunately, at the step *"Enumerating Film Titles and Retrieving Actors Using an HQL Query"* my HQL queries do not give results and instead fail, with the exception:

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from limit 100' at line 1
```

It seems that the HQL isn't generating proper MySQL statements but I can't seem to see why, as I've followed the example to the letter thus far.

I am attempting to connect to a local MySQL database named 'sakila', with the following details:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sakila
```

which seems to work correctly as I am able to browse the tables from within Netbeans no problem.

My hibernate.cfg.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">  
<hibernate-configuration>  
  <session-factory>  
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect</property>  
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>  
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sakila</property>  
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>  
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>  
    <property name="transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>  
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>  
    <property name="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory</property>  
    <mapping resource="dvdrental/Language.hbm.xml"/>  
    <mapping resource="dvdrental/FilmActor.hbm.xml"/>  
    <mapping resource="dvdrental/FilmCategory.hbm.xml"/>  
    <mapping resource="dvdrental/Category.hbm.xml"/>  
    <mapping resource="dvdrental/Film.hbm.xml"/>  
    <mapping resource="dvdrental/Actor.hbm.xml"/>  
  </session-factory>  
</hibernate-configuration>
```

When I'm using the HQL Query window, the SQL it seems to generate only ever says 'select  from ' which is obviously wrong, but I can't see why this is being caused?

**Edit 1:** The HQL Query tab showing my input

[image: Image showing HQL Query tab]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Completely stupid reason- I hadn't even thought about the fact I hadn't built the project, so the example code from the bottom of the example ran properly (cause it came pre-compiled). Works no problem now.

Answer (score 2):

I think the main cause of the error is as stated earlier `from User`, the U in User should be uppercase/capitalized as hibernate uses the POJO. I tried recompiling the code and it works correctly for the sample Swing application: https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/hibernate-java-se.html.

However the HQL Query editor still gives this error. It is strange but seems like this editor is not reliable.

Answer (score 0):

The error message `'from limit 100'` from your posted exception tells me, that you forgot to add `Film` after `from`. Please provide the HQL query that throws the exception.

BTW: the examples in the example project are bad practice. You should never use inline arguments in HQL queries:

```
from Film as film where film.filmId between '"+startID+"' and '"+endID+"'
```

You should use query parameters:

```
Query q = session.createQuery("from Film as film where film.filmId between :startID and :endID");
q.setParameter("startID", startID);
q.setParameter("endID", endID);
```

Comment: As I've now edited to show above, the query I provided was as in the linked project- simply "from Film"

Answer (score 0):

> When I'm using the HQL Query window, the SQL it seems to generate only ever says 'select from ' which is obviously wrong, but I can't see why this is being caused?

A simple

```
from Film
```

is valid HQL and should work. Could you try without the following line:

```
<property name="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory</property>
```

Not sure this will solve the problem but there is no reason to use the "old" parser anyway.

---

> That replaces the problem with a new one I'm afraid. Now the SQL tab of the HQL pane reports 'Invalid Query', and if I run the query I get `org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException`. Any further pointers?

As I said, I was not sure this would solve the problem. What I would do is write a "simple" JUnit test to validate the setup is working. But an obvious bug like this in NetBeans **HQL Query** window is unlikely, IMO.

Comment: That replaces the problem with a new one I'm afraid. Now the SQL tab of the HQL pane reports 'Invalid Query', and if I run the query I get "org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException".. Any further pointers?

Answer (score 0):

> Completely stupid reason- I hadn't even thought about the fact I hadn't built the project, so the example code from the bottom of the example ran properly (cause it came pre-compiled). Works no problem now.

I experienced exactly the same problem but I think your stated solution is not correct. Even your project is not compiled HQL will show you results.
One should be careful of Table name in hibernate.cfg.xml file 
as it should be same in query (case sensitive) also for example in your case it has table name as "Actor" so

`from Actor` will work, not `from actor`